# Magento: storing base url in a config file

Tags: magento

Having multiple development stages, I'd like to keep some magento configurations in a file, and not in the database, so i can have my development version and the production version in sync.

So i need to put in a different place the "base url", that is not the database, because I'd like to export it from production to development

is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible:

```
<default>
    <web>
        <unsecure>
            <base_url>https://foo.dev/</base_url>
        </unsecure>
        <secure>
            <base_url>https://foo.dev/</base_url>
        </secure>
    </web>
</default>
<websites>
    <ws_code>
        <web>
            <unsecure>
                <base_url>http://ws.foo.dev/</base_url>
            </unsecure>
            <secure>
                <base_url>https://ws.foo.dev/</base_url>
            </secure>
        </web>            
    </ws_code>
</websites>
<stores>
    <store_code>
        <web>
            <unsecure>
                <base_url>http://store.foo.dev/</base_url>
            </unsecure>
            <secure>
                <base_url>https://store.foo.dev/</base_url>
            </secure>
        </web>            
    </store_code>
</stores>
```

**However** if anyone ever saves (or has saved) the `System > Configuration > Web` section in the admin, the values in your config file for that scope will not apply.

There are a couple of strategies for protecting your entries

1. Use the file-based config approach and **disable access to the Web section via admin user roles** (for all users). *Caveat: you'll need to provide all of the configuration options in your config.*
2. Use setup scripts (PHP) to write the `base_url` entries to the `core_config_data` table, and protect them from being overwritten via an observer configured under the `adminhtml` event area for the `core_config_data_save_before` event.

You could also combine the observer protection from strategy #2 with the file-based config from strategy #1.

Comment: where should this config file be located?

Comment: If it's part of your module config.

Comment: `app/etc/config.xml?`

Comment: Absolutely not. That is a core file. You could make this part of your module's *`config.xml`*. You could also use the approach of providing any *`.xml`* file in the *`app/etc/`* directory that does not collide with core files.

Comment: It worked like a charm!! and can it be done also for cookies? I tries something like `
      <session_cookie_management>
        <cookie_domain>mydomain.com</cookie_domain>
      </session_cookie_management>` but had no results

Comment: Just find the partial xpath in *`system.xml`* files. For example, the `cookie_domain` xpath is `web/cookie/cookie_domain` - ref https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml#L1394

Comment: I've created a file called baseurl.xml and placed it in app/etc and pasted your code above in (with my domain of course). However, it doesn't work and I get a white screen with the error "Fatal error: Call to a member function extend() on a non-object in /blah/htdocs/mage/dev/src/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 600". Any ideas?

Comment: @PedroKTFC Your file has invalid syntax.

Comment: Well so has your answer then! :o) I've even copied and pasted exactly your answer and I still get the error. Should there be any other tags around it? Thanks muchly btw.

Comment: NP. [All XML documents require a root node to be valid.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element)

Comment: Ben, in case you haven't noticed, I've put the detail of what I've done in an answer below. Still not working, any suggestions?

Comment: Will you move that post to a new question please? That's the "Stack" way of doing things :-)

Comment: Done, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478843/unable-to-set-base-url-from-config-file

Comment: [Although I updated the above question, thought I'd echo my findings here]
 
I finally tracked it down! My settings are being overwritten by those in in `app/code/core/Mage/core/etc/config.xml`. This is a pain as all I want is a simple way of specifying base urls for dev/test/prod type environments. Using a module seems a little OTT for something like this.

Comment: Nope; I promise they are being overwritten by the database-based settings. `Mage_Core` config is merged well before your module; see [`Mage_Core_Model_Config::_getDeclaredModuleFiles()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php#L698). Also, see where the DB config is merged in after file merging in [`Mage_Core_Model_Config::init()`](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.8/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php#L248)