# Move magento from one url to another on the same server

Tags: magento, magento-1.9.1

I have developed a site in the url www.example.com/demo on now i want to move the site to www.example.com on the same server what are the steps that are to be taken to move the site on the same server with the same database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy all the files from demo folder to root folder. Since Database configuration in file will be same, so you don't need to change those. 
In database Run this query

```
SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url';
```

change base secure and unsecure url to www.example.com.

Clear the cache and your are ready with www.example.com

Comment: Can I use system -> configuration -> web and make changes there?

Comment: Yes, U can. For that u have to change secure and insecure url  before moving all files to root folder.

Answer (score 0):

I do a similar thing to you. I have a subsite set up for testing before I push to production. I simply copy the files (using git) and the database whenever I want to update production. However, these are two distinct sites with their own directory structure and database.

So, in order to keep things "simple" (ie I don't need to redo things every time), I have untracked versions of app/etc/local.xml  so each site connects to the right database and on the production system I have a module to set my secure and unsecure urls (see here for more detail than you probably want: [Unable to set base url from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23478843/unable-to-set-base-url-from-config-file/23503170?noredirect=1#comment36126887_23503170)).

Good luck